# echo response clones head files in the echo div

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, echo

After a ajax request, i send the response in a div with class `echo`.
This is my html structure:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="fixed-header>
       <div class="echo"></div>
       ----
```

The ajax looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "",
        type: "POST",
        data:  new FormData(this),

        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(response) {
        $(".echo").html(response);
        },
 });
```

When i look in the DOM after submit, i see that all `head` files like stylesheets and scripts are loaded again. Is that normal and should it be like this? See image below

[image]

**Php code added:**

```
if($_POST['deletefile']) {      

        // if is directory -> remove dir
        if(is_dir($_POST['deletefile'])){

        removeDirectory($_POST['deletefile']);
        include('includes/delete.php'); // echo
        exit;

        }
        // else (must be a file) -> unlink file
        else {

        unlink($_POST['deletefile']);
        include('includes/delete.php'); // echo

        exit;
        }

    return false;   
}
```

Comment: No, it should not be like this. The URL you send the request to seems to have returned a full HTML document, but it should return only the HTML snippet you want to insert into that specific div.

Comment: Where's is the PHP script you're sending the request to?

Comment: What are you passing as the URL?

Comment: `url: "",`  It looks like you're just posting to the current page, so yes, in that case it would be normal.  Undesired, but expected.

Comment: Well, the url of the ajax is empty because the php script is in the same file! I catch it with `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {  `

Comment: @JackMaessen so you may need to use `return false;` at the end of the php script to stop the loading of the reset of the file

Comment: @JackMaessen Show your PHP code

Comment: Post updated with php code @Mohamed-Yousef: `return false` doesnt make sense

Comment: I guess: i have to put all the php code before the `<html>` tag?

Comment: Just make a separate script, that only echos/prints/show on screen the data you want to be returned and change your url parameter to point to that.

Comment: Putting all the php code above the `<html>` tag solved the problem! Thank all for advise